# How to find list of all users in CVS

Tags: version-control, versioning, cvs

I am struggling to find list of all active users in CVS. Do anyone have any idea about the command to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
> cvs log -N 2>&1 | grep author | awk '{ print $6 }' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: It does not shows active users, it shows all users of the CVS, but I want to know the list of active users.

Comment: What do you mean by active?

Comment: Those users which are not deleted and still can perform cvs login are active.